# Support for defining a function - aggregation, mean, t-test, table-output

Tags: r, function, for-loop, aggregate-functions, mean

I am conducting an Event study at the moment. I have like over and over again the same steps for the last parts of my study, therefore I would like to insert these steps into a function that I can just apply. The outputs should be presented in a table.

Here is a MRE of my data:

```
df = data.frame(
  Date_ = 1:15,
  ISIN = rep(c('CH00','CH00', 'GB00'),length.out=15,each=5),
  Return = c(0.0175, -0.0734, -0.0734, 0.0457, 0.0208,-0.0780496, 0.0688210, -0.0064685, -0.0997418, -0.0203781, 0.0056672, 0.0028146, 0.0366418, 0.0745412, 0.1555046),
  Rating_Change = c(0,0,0,1.9,0,0,0,-0.90, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.66, 0, 0),
  Rating = c('A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A', 'A', 'B+','B+','B+','B+','B+'),
  event = c(0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,1,1)
)
df
```

Then I apply the following function to filter for events, that are non-zero - in this example greater than zero.
For "s" I can define the number of the rating change.
For "w" I can define the window for the events.

```
event_up <- function(df, s, w) {
  data_filtered_up <- data.frame()
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (df[i, 4]>s) {
      data_filtered_up[i+w, 1:6] <- filter(df[i+w, 1:6])
      data_filtered_up           <- na.omit(data_filtered_up)
    }
  }
  return(data_filtered_up)
}
```

Now I have these steps to conduct (over and over again for different rating changes and different event windows):

```
TR_event_u_m3          <- event_up(df, 0, -3:-1) #0 defines that the rating change is greater than 0, "-3:-1" defines the pre-event window (3 to 1 month before event)
TR_CAR_u_m3            <- aggregate(.~TR_event_u_m3$ISIN, data=TR_event_u_m3, mean) #aggregating the ISINs to calculate cumulative abnormal returns 
TR_CAR_u_m3            <- TR_CAR_u_m3[,-2][,-2] #deleting non-necessary columns 
TR_CAAR_u_m3           <- mean(TR_CAR_u_m3$AR) #calculate the mean of all cumulative average abnormal returns (CAAR) pre event window
TR_CAAR_u_m3_t         <- t.test(TR_CAR_u_m3$AR) #make t-test for the CAAR
TR_CAAR_table[1,1]     <- TR_CAAR_u_m3 #put CAAR value in table
TR_CAAR_table[2,1]     <- TR_CAAR_u_m3_t$statistic #put t-test for CAAR value in table
```

The output shall be in a specific table, where the rownames describe the event windows with always following the corresponding t-test:

```
TR_CAAR_table           <- matrix(NA, 8, 8)
colnames(TR_CAAR_table) <- c("GSE_U", "E_U", "S_U", "G_U", "GSE_D", "E_D", "S_D", "G_D")
rownames(TR_CAAR_table) <- c("t= -3:-1","t-test -3:-1","t= -1:+1","t-test -1:+1","t= 0:+1","t-test 0:+1","t= +1:+3","t-test +1:+3")
```

Is there a way to integrate the above steps (aggregation, the deleting of the non-necessary columns, the mean, t-test results and the correct placement in the table) into the above mentioned function(event_up), so that I only have to apply the function and not type the steps over and over again for each event window/rating change?

I tried several attempts but there were always errors occurring and I really don't know why. So any help and support is very much appreciated!!
Thank you so much in advance, Antonia

Comment: You could improve your chances of finding help here by adding a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5963610#5963610). Adding a MRE and an example of the desired output (in code form, not tables and pictures) makes it much easier for others to find and test an answer to your question. That way you can help others to help you! P.S. Here is [a good overview on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hello @dario, I added a MRE instead of the data and I tried to clarify my desired output. However, I don't really know the output - this is actually what I am asking for. I hope my edits already help. Thank you for your feedback and inputs.